# Can a mother somehow positively affect fetus during pregnancy?

Tags: human-biology, development, pregnancy, children

My mother keeps telling me that I like to study and have a predisposition to it because she was a student when she was pregnant. I highly doubt it, because I can't find any logic in these words.

I heard that a lot of mothers try to do something to positively affect their fetuses. For example:

1. Listening to classical music.
2. Learning something.
3. Singing or playing musical instruments.

Can these activities somehow affect a child or is it just a myth?

Comment: why the downvote??

Comment: You should reduce your question to a single clearly defined question like `does listening while to classical music in the womb increase the kid's IQ?` Your three questions are too broad. The title question is particularly broad and I suppose the fact that the mother give nutrients to the foetus would be enough to answer yes. I am voting to close as too broad (I was not the one down voting but I can understand the down vote).

Comment: I don't think the question is about any specific activity; those are just examples. The question is can the behaviour of the mother during pregnancy have an effect on the fetus.

Comment: @canadianer Like smoking, drinking alcohol, not feeding yourself correctly, etc.... Shall we make a short list like that and post it as an answer?

Comment: @Remi.b "Can a mother somehow **positively** affect fetus during pregnancy?"

Comment: @Remi.b No, you should not list everything. Especially not things that are obviously not in the spirit of the question.

Comment: @Artmal Not smoking is a way to positively affect the foetus.

Comment: @canadianer It is hard to tell what is `in the spirit of the question` without a accurate definition. I still think the quesiton is too broad and the OP should narrow down to a specific behaviour of interest. It is of course my personal opinion. If other users feel like it is answerable, they can give it a shot.